# pandas dataframe replace % character

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having following dataframe e.g.

```
    symbol  dayHigh dayLow  lastPrice   yearHigh    yearLow previousClose   change  pChange
82  M%M 557 546.6   556 740 502.55  546.6   9.40    1.72
83  M%MFIN  344.4   333.2   343.1   461.45  284.85  332 11.10   3.34
```

I want to replace '%' character starting with 'M%' as 'M%26'

I tried following

```
nifty1['symbol']= np.where(nifty1['symbol'] == 'M%%', 'M%26', nifty1['symbol']) 
nifty1['symbol']= np.where(nifty1['symbol'] == u'M%%', u'M%26', nifty1['symbol'])
```

but it's not successful.

Comment: How about changing `M%%` to `M%` in your `np.where()` clause? As it is`M%%`is not found (2x%% rather than 1x).

Comment: it was not working so tried with %%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pandas majority of string manipulation operations can be found under 'str'. See solution below :

```
df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.replace('M%', 'M%26', regex=False)
```

Edited to match your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not want to replace ALL % but starting with M% important

Comment: thanks for your quick help can we use '^' in this ?

Comment: ```df['symbol'] = df['symbol'].str.replace('M%', 'M%26', regex=False)```?

Comment: If its just another character that you wish to replace then yes you can use whatever you feel like.